# How to compress entire directory keeping it's structure after uncompress?

Tags: io, compression, archive, zip

I understand how to get all files from specified entire directory, but I don't understand how to compress entire directory keeping it's inner structure (I mean inner folders).

I use ZipStorer but I'll be happy to see any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Directory Structure is a separate entity. So you will have to acquire the directory tree structure and store/compress it separately. Upon decompression you will have to recreate this directory tree and explicitly place the files corresponding to their original positions.